# Binary tree recursive search by node content does not return correct node

Tags: c#, search, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I have a binary tree class.

I need to find a first occurrence of a node with some specified content and return this node using recursion.

For example `Find("B")` should find a first occurrence of a node with content "B".

```
public Node Find(string content) 
{
    Node aux = null;
    bool found = false;

    if (this.left != null)
    {
        this.left.Find(content);
    }

    if (found != true)
    {
        if (content == this.content)
        {
            found = true;
            return aux = this;
        }
    }

    if (this.right != null)
    {
        this.right.Find(content);
    }

    return aux;
}
```

Comment: I cant find a solution

Comment: Your function is void and cannot return anything, what is the type of aux ?

Comment: need more code too, what is contenido, what is izq ? lots of puzzling things here.

Comment: ok , sorry mmmmmm this is a code for binary treee , aux is a Node

Comment: Node have, left = izq , rigth = der, and contenido=content

Comment: You do realise you are inventing  hot water don't you. Binary search algorithms can be taken from the internet without hastles.

Comment: aux is defined outside of that method so you are not returning it you are setting it. I think you want to do `return;` after `aux = this;`

Comment: It seems that `aux` is already some instance level variable. You can just access it after the method is run (not that is actually the best way to do a full recursive search over the standard(non-search) binary tree).

Comment: mmm then what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: I meant that 1.  There are [Binary Search Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) and 2. Use of an instance level field to store the result of such function may be a bit superfluous (or not, depending on the whole context of your class).

Comment: ok im going to search in the web , i try to make my own methods because i think that was the best way to learn for my class

Comment: ok i have this code , now what, I can not even find the answer

Comment: @Carlos Obviously someone can give you a complete working code, but will you learn something from such exercise? You won't become better with programming till you understand that changes made without understanding what they change and what they do aren't much better than punching a broken car hoping that it will start. Doing so you are just setting yourself on the path of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @Carlos To deal with this task you have to 1. Describe what this method sholuld be doing (what it accepts, what it returns if succeeds, what if returns if search fails). Don't just think about it - write it, write XML comments for your method, write some tests that will ensure its correctness. 2. Read what recursion is 3. Read why and when do you need to return value from the recursive function 4. Step by step consider the algorithm - use plain paper with some small tree and describe what is going on. 5. When you know what to do - implement the method itself, then check it with prepared tests.

Comment: Thanks man ! @EugenePodskal how can i make u the best answer jaja ?

Comment: @Carlos If you really want then you can self-answer your own question. And do not forget that there are a lot of info over the net regarding all the things programming. StackOverflow is a great place to ask questions, but it is a not a place where you should ask blatant write(fix) my code question - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/3745022 . This question is the result of an attempt to use a partially known technique to solve a new problem. We have all been there and we will all be there many times more. To understand a problem we need an understanding of  both the problem and tools.

Comment: @Carlos Theory is useless without practice, but practice is nearly impossible without a knowledge of theory.

Comment: @Carlos I have edited your question to make it more presentable: 1. There is no need for smiles or helps, thanks - they serve no real purpose. 2. English isn't my native language, but that is not a reason to stop trying to improve it - use Capital letters when sentence starts (and for "I" too), make smaller sentences when you do not know how to combine them in larger, and use spellchecker (SO already uses one to underline typos). 3. It is very difficult to deal with code that uses unknown words as variable names - not everyone here know Spanish? but everyone here can understand English ...

Comment: @Carlos That is not a requirement but it will greatly improve the chances for your future questions. And once more I repeat: before asking - search and read. How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3745022